# Stream Function of Arduino equivalent in Free Rtos ESP-IDF

Tags: arduino, stream, rtos, esp-idf, msi-patch

i am trying to find an equivalent function on ESP-IDF that will be like Stream() of arduino ,
what i am trying to do is to make an MSP function to communicate with the MSP protocol with the ESPs UART, i am using ESP-IDF and Free-Rtos in an Ubuntu environment and cmake to built

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/
https://github.com/yajo10/MSP-Arduino/blob/master/MSP.cpp

i tryied to use std::ostringstream*  but obviously doesnt make the same job

Answer (score 0):

`ostringstream` is a *specialised* `ostream` where the "device" is a memory buffer.  `Stream` is an *unspecialised* base class for a number of device sub-classes, and it is bi-directional.  The standard library equivalent given a suitable stream I/O driver would be `std::istream` and `std::ostream` for input and output respectively, each opened on the specific device. In most cases you would use the derived `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` class s and open the device as a "file stream".

If you require an identical interface in order to use the code unmodified, then implementing `Stream` as a wrapper around `iostream` is feasible.